# emacs python code completion

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, code-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs - tab-completion of local Python variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750267/emacs-tab-completion-of-local-python-variables)

Ok I am getting very confused about this.

What I want is code completion for:

- The current file (even all open buffers)
- Any module that is imported in the current file
- Standard libraries

(yes I have been spoiled by intelli-sense)

What do I need to achieve this?

I'm just really confused as there seem to be countless plugins for code completion, just have no idea which ones I need/want.

Please don't suggest another editor/ide. I know a lot of them have this out of the box, but I really like emacs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have did ["Setup Perfect Python Environment In Emacs"](https://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/), ["AutoComplete.el : Python Code Completion in Emacs"](http://www.enigmacurry.com/2008/05/09/emacs-as-a-powerful-python-ide/), ["My Emacs Python environment"](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/05/my-emacs-python-environment/) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750267/emacs-tab-completion-of-local-python-variables  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856314/python-code-completion not answer your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: I strictly use [melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) package manager now, I install `auto-complete` from there. It is easier. I do not use this method below anymore.

---

I use [autocomplete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) ([docs](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html), [installation instruction](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Installation))

You can install it via `make` (I used this), or by executing `install.el`, or manual installation (byte compiling)

You'll be required to add something to your init.el

```
;;load the auto complete path here, if you havent done it
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

I dont know if there's any tool beside this, but so far this is good enough for me.

Note: this is for auto completion only. If you want a full blown IDE capability you can try those links on comment posted by [huitseeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47978/huitseeker)

Comment: also another tip: put your .emacs.d folder on version control to make your emacs setup portable

Comment: this works allright, but it only seems to complete what has already been written in the current file.  Mostly what I want is completion of imported modules. Like if I 'import urllib' then all the functions of 'urllib' would be added to the auto-complete index.

Comment: It is. By default, auto-complete try to stay out of the way. If you want it to show you auto-completion choices all the time, set `ac-auto-start`to `t`, but you still have to type the first character. You can customize it further if you're not satisfied yet by changing the configuration.

Comment: I managed to integrate ropemacs and yasnippet into auto-complete with the help of this guide http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/   WOrks pretty well.

Comment: The autocomplete links are dead